# Spark job fails to launch on Kubernetes cluser

Tags: java, apache-spark, ssl, kubernetes

I am trying run a spark job on kubernetes cluster with

```
./bin/spark-submit     --master k8s://https://<master-ip-addr>:6443    --deploy-mode cluster     --name spark-pi     --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi     --conf spark.executor.instances=5     --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<hub-user>/spark     local:///path/to/examples.jar
```

When I run above command from my local machine I get following error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at 
sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) at 
sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:119) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:66) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:109) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135) at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317) at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ... 39 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445) ... 45 more Exception in thread "kubernetes-dispatcher-0" Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@22c3ccc0 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1ef5330b[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:632) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:678) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager.scheduleReconnect(WatchConnectionManager.java:300) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager.access$800(WatchConnectionManager.java:48) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager$2.onFailure(WatchConnectionManager.java:213) at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.java:543) at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onFailure(RealWebSocket.java:208) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:148) at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failed to start websocket at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager$2.onFailure(WatchConnectionManager.java:204) at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.java:543) at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onFailure(RealWebSocket.java:208) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:148) at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:119) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:66) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:109) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185) at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135) ... 4 more Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317) at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237) at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ... 39 more Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445) ... 45 more 2020-02-09 16:57:32 INFO ShutdownHookManager:58 - Shutdown hook called
```

I dont understand this error. Whats going wrong ? How do I resolve it ?

Comment: You are accessing the https protocol but it seems that you don't have the correct certificate.

Comment: I assume you're running `spark-submit` from a local machine. Have you logged in to the cluster? Can you run such command as `kubectl cluster-info`, `kubectl get pods`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to stacktrace, it is caused when the Java environment does not have information about the HTTPS server to verify that it is a valid website.

> `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

### `keytool` to fix SSL issue

You can use `keytool`:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619478/5720818) or [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/5720818)

- Check if your certificate is already in the truststore by running the following command: `keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`
- Add the certificate for `<master-ip-addr>` to the truststore file of the used JVM located at `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts`:

  - If your certificate is missing, you can get it by downloading it with your browser and add it to the truststore with the following command: `keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>`
  - After import you can run the first command again to check if your certificate was added.
- Restart your JVM

### InstallCert.java

- Get [InstallCert.java](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert)
- Run [InstallCert.java, with your hostname and https port, and press 1 when ask for input. It will add your localhost as a trusted keystore, and generates a file `jssecacerts`

```
java InstallCert <master-ip-addr>:6443
```

Answer (score 0):

You have either to configure the connection to your Kubernetes Cluster like you would do for `kubectl` by placing the Kubeconfig file in a file ~/.kube/cofig or set the spark submit parameters for authentication correctly

```
spark-submit \
... \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile=path_to_cert_file \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.oauthTokenFile=path_to_token \
file_to_execute.jar
```

You have to use different parameters depending if you start in cluster or client mode
All possible configurations for authentication are listed in the documentation
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#configuration